# CakePHP2.3 : ajax submit not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Ajax submission not working.Here my controller code.

```
if ($this->UserType->save($this->request->data)) {
        if($this->request->isAjax()){
        $this->render('success','ajax');
}
```

I have made a success.ctp in UserTypes folder.

```
<p style="background-color:green;">Massage Sent</p>
```

In add.ctp file I have add bellow code.

```
<?php 
        echo $this->js->submit('Send',array(
        'update'=>'#success',
        'class'=>'btn btn-danger',
        'style'=>'width:45%;margin-top:1%;height:30px;'
    ));  
?>
```

I have add a html div under button

```
<div id="success"></div>
```

I don't know where is the problem ? Why it is not working ?

Comment: If you use firefox install firebug and check what response the ajax request is sending. makes it alto easier to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem after big journey !! Here the problem is I have used `$this->js->submit`  It will be actually `$this->Js->submit`. Capital J.